# Eclipse not recognise samsung s5660

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adb

I'm in Eclipse using the Android Device Chooser, but the chooser does not my Samsung s5660 device.  Is this problem with the phone, with linux or with Eclipse? I am using Ubuntu, if that matters.

[image]

Solved.

I'm create  rules for udev in /etc/udev/rules.d. In rules I'm write "SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8:689e", MODE="0666"" where SYSFS{idVendor} is your id device (see in lsusb).

Then in console

sudo adb kill-server, sudo adb start-server, adb devices

Comment: This is not an Eclipse problem, but related to the Android SDK. `adb` does not recognize your phone correctly. You could try to run `adb devices` from the command line to see if it also has this problem.

Comment: If you were on a PC, I would tell you to download the driver manually and install it.  Are you using a Mac?

Comment: I'm using linux(Ubuntu).I don't think is problem in driver. This out from command "lsusb" "Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e8:689e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-S5670 [Galaxy Fit]"

Comment: This is out from command "adb devices" "List of devices attached 
???????????? no permissions"